# How to make a parabola rotate around its vertex?

Tags: pgfplots

I can't find any discussion about this particular problem. New to LaTeX here.

I have the parabola x = -(y - 3) + 3. It should be horizontal and open to the left.

pgfplots gives me the error "Sorry, you can't use "y" in that context" when I try to compile it.

The coordinates in the first \addplot are where the parabola *should* be.

```
\documentclass[pstricks, 12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{top=1.5cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}
    \begin{flushright}
    \end{flushright}
\begin{addmargin}[0em]{15em}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[width=10cm, height=10cm, xmin=-12, xmax=12, ymin=-12, ymax=12, axis lines = middle, xlabel=x, ylabel=y,
            xtick={-12, -10,...,12},
            minor xtick={-11, -9,...,11},
            ytick={-12, -10,...,12},
            minor ytick={-11, -9,...,11},
            tick style={very thick},
            grid=both, ]
            \addplot [blue, only marks] coordinates {
                (3, 3)
                (0, {3 + sqrt(3)}) 
                (0, {3 - sqrt(3)}) 
                (-6, 6)
                (0, {3 - sqrt(3)})
                (-6, 0)};
            \addplot [blue, no marks, <->, line width=1]{-(y - 3)^2 + 3};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{addmargin}
\end{document}
```

So I do some research and find out about the rotate option. I change the x to a y and add rotate=-90.

However, it appears to rotate the parabola around some far off point that results in it disappearing.

I figured this out by changing rotate=-90 to rotate=-5 in the following code. The parabola is partially rotating around some point way in the negative y axis.

It is rotating in the correct direction but around the wrong point. Can I make it rotate around the vertex somehow?
Thanks for any help!

```
\documentclass[pstricks, 12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{top=1.5cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}
    \begin{flushright}
    \end{flushright}
\begin{addmargin}[0em]{15em}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[width=10cm, height=10cm, xmin=-12, xmax=12, ymin=-12, ymax=12, axis lines = middle, xlabel=x, ylabel=y,
            xtick={-12, -10,...,12},
            minor xtick={-11, -9,...,11},
            ytick={-12, -10,...,12},
            minor ytick={-11, -9,...,11},
            tick style={very thick},
            grid=both, ]
            \addplot [blue, only marks] coordinates {
                (3, 3)
                (0, {3 + sqrt(3)}) 
                (0, {3 - sqrt(3)}) 
                (-6, 6)
                (0, {3 - sqrt(3)})
                (-6, 0)};
            \addplot [blue, no marks, <->, line width=1, rotate=-5]{-(x - 3)^2 + 3};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{addmargin}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

With a `tikz` code (minimal, but with axes and grid):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
        \draw[gray!20] (-13,-1) grid (9,20);
        \draw[-latex] (-13,0)--(9,0) node[right] () {x};
        \draw[-latex] (0,-1)--(0,20) node[above] () {y}; 
    \draw[line width=1pt,dashed] plot[domain=-1:7,smooth] (\x,{\x*\x-6*\x+12});
    \draw[rotate around={90:(3,3)},red,line width=2pt] plot[domain=-1:7,smooth] (\x,{\x*\x-6*\x+12});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Bravo, how simple!+1.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

For desired result you should try to draw inversion function: `y=sqrt(x-3)+3`:

```
%\documentclass[pstricks, 12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%width=10cm, height=10cm, 
    axis lines = middle, 
    grid=both,
    minor tick num = 1,
    minor grid style = {densely dashed, very thin},
    axis on top,
%
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, 
    xmin=-10, xmax=10, 
    ymin=-10, ymax=10,
    enlargelimits=0.05, 
    xtick={-10,-8,...,10},
    ytick={-10,-8,...,10},
    ticklabel style={fill=white, font=\scriptsize,
                     inner sep=1pt, outer sep=1pt},
%
    samples=501, no marks,
every axis plot post/.append style={blue, line width=1}
            ]
\addplot [blue, only marks] coordinates {
                (3, 3)
                (0, {3 + sqrt(3)})
                (0, {3 - sqrt(3)})
                (-6, 6)
                (0, {3 - sqrt(3)})
                (-6, 0)};
\addplot +[->, domain =4:-9]    {-sqrt(-x+3)+3};
\addplot +[<-, domain =-9:4]    {+sqrt(-x+3)+3};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
Simpler solution using `tikz` is shown in @Raffaele Santoro answer (+1). Here is shown, that his nice idea works fine also with using `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=10cm, height=10cm,
    axis lines = middle,
    grid=both,
    minor tick num = 1,
    minor grid style = {densely dashed, very thin},
    axis on top,
%
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
    xmin=-10, xmax=10,  xtick distance = 2,
    ymin=-10, ymax=10,  ytick distance = 2,
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    ticklabel style={fill=white, font=\scriptsize,
                     inner sep=1pt, outer sep=1pt},
%
    domain =-0.5:6.5, samples=101, no marks,
every axis plot post/.append style={blue, thick, <->}
            ]
\addplot [blue, only marks] coordinates {
                (3, 3)
                (0, {3 + sqrt(3)})  (0, {3 - sqrt(3)})
                (-6, 3 + 3)         (-6, 3 - 3)};
\addplot [rotate around={90:(3,3)}]   {(x - 3)^2 + 3};
\addplot [dashed]    {(x - 3)^2 + 3};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]